# max-width property does not work for children of the flex-item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I Set `display:Flex` to the `.container` element. I had put two children on the element. and gave max-width to the child(`.box`) of second flex-Item. But it does not seems to work.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.par {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 7px
}

.round {
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background: #cacaca;
  border-radius: 50%
}

.box {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  max-width: 200px;
  left: -11px;
  top: 28px;
}

.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  transform: rotate(-137deg);
  top: -5px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="par">
    <div class="round"></div>
    <div class="box">This is a Paragraph Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0sxLyjf4/2/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
Try replace `max-width` with `width`. See if it is what you want.

Comment: I want a width to its content's size.so I didn't set width. but when content size increse, i want to break a content to the next line. so, I Set max-width

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute` child's width depends on it's `position: relative` parent.

In your case, `.box`'s width depends on `.par` while `.par` is too narrow to contain the word "Paragraph". That's why the `.box`'s width is depending to the its longest word in the content.

[image: ]1]]

I don't think you can set dynamic width to `.box` while not exceeding `200px` and also keep the current width of `.par`. There maybe 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. set `.par`'s to `width: 200px`
2. set fixed `width: 200px` to `.box`

Answer (score 0):

You need remove `position: relative` for `.par` and remove `left and top` for `.box` instead add styles for `.box` like `margin: 8px 0 0 -11px;`, than max-width will be work correct.